# how to get gmail attachment file name in google-chrome / chromium?

Tags: c++, gtk

```cpp
GSList * gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames ( GtkFileChooser* chooser )
{

        GSList* (*new_gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames) ( GtkFileChooser* chooser );
        new_gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames=(GSList* (*)( GtkFileChooser* )) gtkFunctionAddr("gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames");
        char *filename = NULL,s[1024];
        GSList *list = (*new_gtk_file_chooser_get_filenames) ((chooser));
        GSList *it = list;
        GSList *ki = NULL;
        int f=0;
        GtkWindow *parent;

        while(it!=NULL)
        {
                filename = (char *)it->data;

                printf("File name :- '%s'",filename);
         }
 return ki;
}
```

Comment: You probably want to advance `it` to the next element by the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.